# How does blocking mode in unix/linux sockets works?

Tags: c, linux, networking, sockets, kernel

Does blocking mode put that particular task in a "Process Wait" state, as i think non-blocking sockets needs a "busy-wait" or "spin-lock" implementation, explicitly from the user. Or blocking mode sockets are nothing but implicit-implementations of busy-wait by the kernel.

In locking mechanisms like semaphores/mutexes/monitors a lock is usually achieved by pushing the task in Blocked State. I think if such things are possible with locking, then socket locking might also be achieved by same way.

I dont know for sure, I think polling is not a efficient way, esp for the kernel, as the kernel always has his hands full with so many tasks.

thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what i learnt from net/book/ and provided answers. I will try to be to the point.

> By default all sockets are blocking. This means that when we issues a socket call that cannot be completed immediately, our process is put to sleep, waiting for the condition to be ture. *unp -- p435*

Sleep is implemented by putting the process in the wait/blocked state. Scheduler checks for the condition to un-block the process, when the blocked process get it turn, ie when the scheduler give him the CPU. The responsiveness in this case depends on the time resolution of the scheduler.

So, the blocking calls are not implicit implementation of "busy wait" or "spin lock" from the kernel.

Yes underlying mechanism of locking is same for most of the implementations. Putting process to blocked/wait state.

Of-course polling was not efficient, ie why blocking is not implemented using polling.

Answer (score 9):

No, blocking sockets are implemented in the kernel. The process is into a non-executing state, and does not consume any CPU time.

The kernel is free to run other tasks until some outside activity would cause it to wake the task up. For instance, a hardware interrupt for the network card letting it know there is data to be read. The kernel reads it and pushes it through the network stack, eventually waking up the application to process the data.

Timers would work the same way, but with the timer interrupt.

The kernel *might* actually be polling hardware under the hood, but it doesn't have to be... that's all a matter of how the hardware is designed.

Comment: @Chris - What is "put aside". A process has to be in one of the states. By "put aside" do you mean wait state, but that i what i asked in the question. I myself have no idea, as i think polling is not a efficient way, esp for the kernel, esp when the kernel always has his hands full with so many taks.

Comment: When blocked on a blocking socket operation, the process will be in Sleep state ("S" in the STAT column of ps).

Comment: "By put aside" I think Chris means the operating system will put it on the list of processes waiting on input.  The process will not be woken up by the OS until it receives a packet directed to the port bound to the socket that's being read.

Comment: Just a cygil said... The specifics depend on the operating system, but the task goes into some sort of "sleeping" state in which it is not executed, and is on a list of task awaiting input. Once the input is available, the task is woken up and marked ready to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080805/c-how-does-sleep-and-cin-work/1080836#1080836) to this question: [C++ - how does Sleep() and cin work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080805/c-how-does-sleep-and-cin-work)