# Windows batch: sleep

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, scripting

How do I get a Windows batch script to wait a few seconds?

`sleep` and `wait` don't seem to work (unrecognized command).

Answer (score 183, accepted):

You can try

```
ping -n XXX 127.0.0.1 >nul
```

where XXX is the number of seconds to wait, plus one.

Comment: [Clay Calvert](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/msg/804a9fa0f5864558?pli=1) provides an explanation of this technique. Note that `-n` is used to indicate the number of requests. `ping` waits one second by default for each reply even if it arrives in less time.

Comment: remember you need to add one to the number of seconds, because ping doesn't wait before the first request.

Comment: Haha, so simple and yet so genius :-) Exactly what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Only thing I could find that worked on plain XP.

Comment: I ran into a funny issue using this method when I needed a script to automatically release the computer's IP address, wait a few minutes while I reconfigured a switch port, and then renew the IP address.  During the intervening moments that the switch port was down, the network connection was lost and ping errored out with a `hardware error` message, and ran through the supposedly 1-second long pings in a fraction of the expected time.

Comment: Yes, the SLEEP command doesn't seem to work for me too. Windows 10. Neat hack

Comment: For the `XXX=1` it exits immediately (Windows 7). Works only if `XXX>1`.

Comment: To wait in milliseconds may be this one fits better: `pathping localhost -n -q 1 -p XXX >nul`, where `XXX` is in milliseconds. Notice, if `localhost` is invalid ip address, then it exits immediately.

Answer (score 180):

I don't know why those commands are not working for you, but you can also try [timeout](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)

```
timeout <delay in seconds>
```

Comment: i have plain windows XP install. i think "sleep" is an addition you have to install. `timeout` works great, though, thanks!

Comment: Ooh! I didn't know about timeout. Unfortunately it isn't available in Windows 2000, although that probably isn't a problem nowadays. If it is, choice will work on previous versions too (even in DOS).

Comment: I haven't used this command - I just found it in [ss64](http://www.ss64.com). You may also want to take a look at [lukuluku's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317020/windows-batch-sleep/4317114#4317114).

Comment: this works in Windows 7

Comment: [The TIMEOUT command was introduced in Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Sleep_or_scripted_delay).

Comment: **N.B.** And if you don't want the message `Waiting for x seconds, press any key` to be displayed in the console, you can use `timeout delayInSecs >nul`, then it waits silently and continues when the time has elapsed. Bear in mind that it still reacts on any key (meaning someone pressing a key may interrupt the waiting of the script if the console in which the batch runs is the active window).

Comment: It's so weird -- I have windows 10, and it `sleep` works on my PC, but on a VM in Azure, which also has the *latest* Windows 10, it DOESN'T work. -- Luckily the ping trick above works fine.

Comment: Just one side note: timeout command lets you specify up to 99999 seconds (about 27 hours). If you need more wait time, you have to use the ping command, that can handle up to 2^32 seconds (ping -n XXX 127.0.0.1 >nul)

Answer (score 173):

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak > NUL
```

`/t` specifies the time to wait in seconds

`/nobreak` won't interrupt the timeout if you press a key (except CTRL-C)

`> NUL` will suppress the output of the command

Comment: This is what I have been looking for and couldn't find anywhere.  +1

Comment: The TIMEOUT command does not work on Windows XP; [it was introduced in Windows Vista.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Sleep_or_scripted_delay).

Comment: On my XP machine here i have it. @PeterMortensen Did it got in via update?

Comment: Absolutely no explanation? Please elaborate on your 3 parameters. `/t`, `/nobreak` and `> NUL`.

Comment: @Heberda `/t` Time to wait in seconds, `/nobreak` won't interrupt the timeout if you press a button (except `CTRL-C`), `> NUL` will suppress the output of the command

Answer (score 14):

To wait 10 seconds:

```
choice /T 10 /C X /D X /N
```

Comment: i'll use this with `> NUL` to suppress all output.

Comment: woah actually i have neither timeout nor choice on this install of xp i'm working with... really weird. ping it is.

Comment: The CHOICE command does not work on Windows XP; [it was introduced in Windows 2003 and Windows Vista.](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Turns out `Choice` is available for Windows XP but it is not installed by default. It wasn't introduced in Windows 2003, though, because it existed in [earlier consumer versions](http://www.computerhope.com/choicehl.htm) (95, 98) of Windows and even in MSDOS 6.0. They probably just forgot about it when they combined the consumer versions with the NT versions starting with Windows 2000. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft has a sleep function you can call directly.

```
    Usage:  sleep      time-to-sleep-in-seconds
            sleep [-m] time-to-sleep-in-milliseconds
            sleep [-c] commited-memory ratio (1%-100%)
```

You can just say **sleep 1** for example to sleep for 1 second in your batch script.

IMO Ping is a bit of a hack for this use case.

Comment: "C:\Documents and Settings\User>sleep
'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Windows is a bit of a hack for this use case.. lol

Comment: I could use 'sleep' on my machine (windows 7).

Comment: PowerShell or plain cmd.exe?

Comment: [PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) indeed. Good catch @RandomInsano!

Comment: Confirmed - it is a POWER SHELL command, not regular command line (cmd.exe)

Comment: works fine in my Win8 CMD

Answer (score 6):

For a pure cmd.exe script, you can use this piece of code that returns the current time in hundreths of seconds.

```
:gettime
set hh=%time:~0,2%
set mm=%time:~3,2%
set ss=%time:~6,2%
set cc=%time:~-2%
set /A %1=hh*360000+mm*6000+ss*100+cc
goto :eof
```

You may then use it in a wait loop like this.

```
:wait
call :gettime wait0
:w2
call :gettime wait1
set /A waitt = wait1-wait0
if !waitt! lss %1 goto :w2
goto :eof
```

And putting all pieces together:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

call :gettime t1
echo %t1%
call :wait %1
call :gettime t2
echo %t2%
set /A tt = (t2-t1)/100
echo %tt%
goto :eof

:wait
call :gettime wait0
:w2
call :gettime wait1
set /A waitt = wait1-wait0
if !waitt! lss %1 goto :w2
goto :eof

:gettime 
set hh=%time:~0,2%
set mm=%time:~3,2%
set ss=%time:~6,2%
set cc=%time:~-2%
set /A %1=hh*360000+mm*6000+ss*100+cc
goto :eof
```

For a more detailed description of the commands used here, check `HELP SET` and `HELP CALL` information.

Comment: But that is a "busy wait" loop burning CPU time unnecessarily. Calling a command which waits is better in my opinion. Please consider [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107593/what-are-trade-offs-for-busy-wait-vs-sleep) at SO to find out more. In order to mitigate this in your script you could insert `timeout x >nul` after the `:wait` label (replace x by the number of seconds to wait)

Comment: This is unreliable on international Windows as it is tied to date and time localization.

Answer (score 5):

Heh, Windows is uhm... interesting. This works:

```
choice /T 1 /d y > NUL
```

`choice` presents a prompt asking you yes or no. `/d y` makes it choose yes. `/t 1` makes it wait a second before typing it. `> NUL` squashes output.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to have a Windows that asks Yes or No. On my Dutch Windows, it asks Ja or Nee, so the Y won't work. Thats why I specified the exact choices in my answer above. And you can just add /N to prevent the prompt to be displayed.

Comment: @GolezTrol: still need the "> NUL" to supress the "X" from displaying. ah and I didn't realize the importance of "/C" , the example i found online had it

Comment: The CHOICE command does not work on Windows XP; [it was introduced in Windows 2003 and Windows Vista.](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html).

Comment: hahaha goofy +1

Answer (score 5):

I rely on [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript). I have a JScript file like this:

```
// This is sleep.js
WScript.Sleep( WScript.Arguments( 0 ) );
```

And inside a batch file I run it with [CScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host#Available_scripting_engines) (usually it is `%SystemRoot%\system32\cscript.exe`)

```
rem This is the calling inside a BAT file to wait for 5 seconds
cscript /nologo sleep.js 5000
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Windows 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en) has a `sleep` batch file. If you ever move up to [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), you can use:

```
Start-Sleep -s <time to sleep>
```

Or something like that.

Comment: ...or `powershell -command "Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000">nul`

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote my own sleep which called the [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) [Sleep API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: /* Compile this with ms vc6, cl.exe Sleep.c, e.g. Sleep.exe 100  .. sleep for 100 ms */
#include <WinSock.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { Sleep(argc<2?1000:atoi(argv[1])); return 0; }

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use a [Perl one-liner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program#Perl):

```
perl -e "sleep 10;"
```

for a 10-second wait. Chances are you'll already have Perl installed on a development machine as part of your git installation; if not you will have to install it, for example, from [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads) or [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/), but it's one of those things I install anyway.

Alternatively, you can install a sleep command from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: ah it isn't one of those things I install =P. i don't even want to install a "sleep.exe" utility, so this is a bit much.

Comment: Ruby would work too: `ruby -e "sleep 10"` -- and it's one character less :)

Comment: @Roy: Actually, perl can do without the semicolon. And if you can get away with 9 seconds instead of 10, it is even TWO characters less: `perl -e "sleep 9"` :-)

Comment: You can also use PHP like this: php -r sleep(5);

Comment: Here's another interpreter: `node -e "setTimeout(a=>{}, 500)"`

Answer (score 1):

[RJLsoftware](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/) has a small utility called [DelayExec.exe](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/). With this you can execute a delayed start of any program in batches and Windows registry (most useful in ...Windows/.../Run registry).

Usage example:

```
delayexec "C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" 10
```

or as a sleep command:

```
delayexec "nothing" 10
```