# Appending output of a Batch file To log file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which calls a java program.

The output is redirected to a log file in the same directory.
However the log file is replaced everytime the batch file is run...

I would like to keep the old outputs in the log file and always append the new output to the log file.

Comment: How do you redirect output ALSO to console as well as the log file?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Instead of using ">" to redirect like this:

```
java Foo > log
```

use ">>" to append normal "stdout" output to a new or existing file:

```
java Foo >> log
```

However, if you also want to capture "stderr" errors (such as why the Java program couldn't be started), you should also use the "2>&1" tag which redirects "stderr" (the "2") to "stdout" (the "1").  For example:

```
java Foo >> log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, ">>" worked.....also can you please tell me what lines should i add to my batch file which will make it execute after every 30mins.....along with the Timestamp!

Comment: @Monojeet: You probably shouldn't do that in your batch file - instead, use Task Scheduler.

Comment: Actually this thing is going to be deployed accross many servers, so not possible to configure task scheduler on every server, a script will be handy!

Comment: @Monojeet: Well you're basically talking about writing your own scheduler as a script... which doesn't sound like a good idea to me. I'm sure it's possible to remotely configure scheduled tasks, and that would be a better way to go, IMO. If you *really* want to avoid that, I'd put the scheduling in a "proper" program (whether that's Java, a C# wrapper or whatever) rather than trying to do it in a batch file.

Comment: @Monojeet: You could always make your batch file *invoke* the Windows Task Scheduler, of course, using "at".

Comment: "javaprog %1 %2 >>test.log".....how can i add a timestamp(date and time) to the log file...

Comment: @Monojeet: Well, you could run "date /t >> test.log" and "time /t >> test.log" beforehand, assuming you can't change the Java code.

Comment: @John:- yeah , i shud have easily done that if i cud change my code..i have already written the code and checked in :) ...basically its a monitoring java prog which returns certain error codes for a infrastructure...i need to call this java prog at certain intervals( 3mins) so that the monitoring team can pick the error codes and send notifications...Simple!! I have done this thing in Unix...just used the sleep command in the wrapper script....but dont know how do i do that in windows!

Comment: @Monojeet: Just because you've checked in the code doesn't mean you can't change it any further... I'd hope, anyway. Otherwise it had better be *perfect* to start with...  On Unix I'd use cron rather than sleeping, for a monitoring program.

Comment: @John:- ok , will change the code, was just trying to learn it through the batch file....Thanks a lot for you reply....i saw your profile...it was an honor speaking to you...cheers!

Answer (score 4):

*This is not an answer to your original question: "Appending output of a Batch file To log file?"*

**For reference, it's an answer to your followup question: "What lines should i add to my batch file which will make it execute after every 30mins?"**

(But I would take Jon Skeet's advice: "You probably shouldn't do that in your batch file - instead, use Task Scheduler.")

Timeout:

- [`timeout` command 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file/5483958#5483958)
- [`timeout` command 2](https://superuser.com/questions/48231/how-do-i-make-a-batch-file-wait-sleep-for-some-seconds/110658#110658)

Example (1 second):

`TIMEOUT /T 1000 /NOBREAK`

Sleep:

- [`sleep` command (if sleep.exe is installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317020/windows-batch-sleep/6943703#6943703)

Example (1 second):

`sleep -m 1000`

Alternative methods:

- [Sleeping in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file/6806192#6806192)
- [batch script, put to sleep until certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733850/batch-script-put-to-sleep-until-certain-time/8737084#8737084)

Here's an answer to your 2nd followup question: "Along with the Timestamp?"

[Create a date and time stamp in your batch files](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2007/02/create-a-date-and-time-stamp-in-your-batch-files/)

Example:

`echo *** Date: %DATE:/=-% and Time:%TIME::=-% *** >> output.log`

Answer (score 0):

Use log4j in your java program instead.  Then you can output to multiple media, create rolling logs, etc. and include timestamps, class names and line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use `java Foo | tee -a some.log`. it just prints to stdout as well. Like:

```
user at Computer in ~
$ echo "hi" | tee -a foo.txt
hi

user at Computer in ~
$ echo "hello" | tee -a foo.txt
hello

user at Computer in ~
$ cat foo.txt
hi
hello
```