# Can I add a log write to my batch file?

Tags: batch-file

As this question points out [Appending output of a Batch file To log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458231/appending-output-of-a-batch-file-to-log-file) I can write to a log file when running a batch job simply by using the pipe command ">".

However, what I'd really like to do is have the job write to my log file automatically - without having to run it from console (So that I can just double-click it when I want to run a build).  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the shortcut and select `properties`. Change the `target` by appending `>logfilename` to create a new logfile, or `>>logfilename` to append to any existing logfile. Click Apply, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect every command within the batch file to a log.

Or you can make a wrapper batch file that calls the original and redirects it.