# Batch file - Display text for 5 seconds

Tags: batch-file

How can I display my data from x.bat for 5 seconds?

When this code runs, it's impossible for me to see anything, it opens and closes immediately.

```
@ECHO OFF
:BEGIN
ECHO Authorized user
:END
```

If I use pause, the user still needs to hit a key to close the screen, that's why this should happen automatically.

```
@ECHO OFF
:BEGIN
ECHO Authorized user
pause
:END
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4317020/11343

Answer (score 3):

```
@ECHO OFF
:BEGIN
ECHO Authorized user
timeout 5 >nul
cls
:END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab "sleep.exe" from the Windows Server 2003 resource kit and use `sleep [seconds]` but the easiest way to get a set delay is to simply ping localhost N+1 times, where N is the number of seconds.

This will sleep for five seconds (there's no delay before the first ping, and a 1s delay after each):

```
ping -n 6 localhost>nul
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SLEEP 5
GOTO:EOF
```

Would wait for 5 seconds before closing the window.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Vista and later you can use `timeout`:

```
timeout 5 >nul
```

On ancient Windows versions you need to resort to `ping`:

```
ping -n 6 localhost >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to use `ping`, which also seems to be slightly less precise:

```
ping -n 1 -w 5000 1.0.0.0 >null
```

That is, convert seconds to milliseconds and use that as an argument of `-w` parameter. The `-n` parameter should have the argument of `1`. The host should be a knowingly inaccessible IP address.

Answer (score 0):

variety of ways to resolve this

```
timeout /t 5 /nobreak >Nul
::for 5 sec

@PING 1.1.1.1 -n 2 -w 3000>nul
 :: -n 2 for around 5-6 seconds

sleep 5 (EMERGENCY CASE)
```