# Sleep/Wait command in Batch

Tags: batch-file, wait, sleep

I want to add time delay in my batch file. The batch file will be running silently at backgorund. Please help me.

Comment: windows XP, windows 7, Vista both 64 and 32 bit

Comment: It is hard to help you without more information. What batch language? What have you tried so far? What system? How long of a delay? _All_ of these items are necessary to provide a good answer.

Comment: See [windows batch: sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317020/windows-batch-sleep).

Comment: Just I want to use a DOS commands to run a batch file at the backgorund. The OS I am going to use XP,Vista and Win7. Expecting dleay is amay be about 3-10 seconds. I tried the batch with out delay, but its not deleting a folder since that is used by another application. so  I have to wait for few seconds for the exit

Comment: The ping command popping up the command prompt.. the batch should run at back end.. can we hide the command prompt..

Answer (score 38):

`timeout 5`

to delay

`timeout 5 >nul`

to delay without asking you to press any key to cancel

Comment: Full sintax is available with TIMEOUT /?

Comment: There's a `/nobreak` option. Also note that [timeout cannot run in background](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/timeout-command-run-batch-job-exits-immediately-and-returns-error-input-redirection-not-supported-exiting-process-immediately).

Answer (score 5):

You want to use timeout.

```
timeout 10
```

will sleep 10 seconds

Comment: How to use timeout silently.. the cmmand prompt should not be displayed

Comment: you should probably look into using actual programming language to do this then.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166044/sleeping-in-a-batch-file for python, c++, perl, etc examples

Comment: @HPFE455 - simply redirect the output to nul: `>nul timeout 10`

Answer (score 5):

```
ping localhost -n (your time) >nul
```

example

```
@echo off
title Test
echo hi
ping localhost -n 3 >nul && :: will wait 3 seconds before going next command (it will not display)
echo bye! && :: still wont be any spaces (just below the hi command)
ping localhost -n 2 >nul && :: will wait 2 seconds before going to next command (it will not display)
@exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yup you use the `timeout` command to sleep. But to do the whole process silently, it's not possible with cmd/batch. One of the ways is to create a **VBScript** that will run the **Batch File** without opening/showing any window.
And here is the script:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "PATH OF BATCH FILE WITH QUOTATION MARKS" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**Copy and paste the above code on notepad and save it as 
*Anyname*.**vbs**
**
An example of the *"PATH OF BATCH FILE WITH QUOTATION MARKS" * might be: 
"C:\ExampleFolder\MyBatchFile.bat"