# Repeatedly execute a Windows command from a batch file?

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd, shutdown

I'm not too familiar with batch files for Windows, so this may seem like a beginner question.  How could I "loop", or repeat, a command like the following?

```
shutdown -a
```

Comment: Do you want to repeat it a fixed number of times?  Repeat it until some condition occurs?  Or, perhaps it would just be more useful if you could explain the broader goal you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @reuben - I've have someone beside me at work who likes to play around and hit the power button on my terminal. When he does I bring up the run box and type in the "shutdown -a" command but bout 50% of the time the computer is past the point of return and can't be stopped from shutting down so I thought I'd just loop it constantly.

Comment: Sorry to hear you have to deal with that!  Have you looked into changing how your PC reacts to the power button getting hit?  Holding down the reset button for a few seconds usually can't be canceled, but a quick push might be software interruptible...

Comment: @reuben - hmmm that's a good fix. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 7):

I agree with commenter @reuben, that you possible should look for other options (including getting that coworker himself "fixed"), but anyway here is a way to run the command repeatedly:

```
:loop
shutdown -a
goto loop
```

Note that this might still leave a window, where it cannot cancel a shutdown because it is not "fast" enough.

Also it causes "mild terror" to your system, at least on the `csrss.exe` (or `conhost.exe`) process, because the console window will be busy printing messages. Thus you might want to redirect the output at least (`shutdown -a > NUL 2>&1`) and/or introduce some [delay](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4317020/21567) beteween the calls to `shutdown`. Of course the later increases the risk of not "catching" a shutdown significantly.

All in all that is not a good solution to your problem. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to shutdown multiple remote computers?  You can write a script that ssh into each machine and send it the shutdown command:

```
ssh user1@remote_computer1 shutdown
ssh user2@remote_computer2 shutdown
...
```

If you mean you what to loop the shutdown command on the same computer, you can put the shutdown command in your ~/.bashrc, if you really want to.  But make sure you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: Are you assuming that the OP has `ssh`, `bash`, and other Unix tools installed on the Windows machines in question?

Comment: @LMC - No 'Shutdown -a' at least on windows is a command to abort shutdown

Comment: @Reuben - Unless Windows has them pre-installed they probably wouldn't be on the computer and I think I would get in trouble for adding things

Comment: You are entirely correct.  I don't know how I could have completed missed the word "Windows" in the question.  Sorry about that.