# How to retrieve ping data through a command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, ping

Is it possible to retrieve the data output when you type ping in the command line?

Currently, we have existing servers that we check daily by typing ping (IP address) in the command line but only during at the start of the day. We would only be notified if the server is down once the user notifies us. The manual thing to do is to do a continuous ping and do a timely check of whether it was disconnected or not.

I would like to create something that would give out a prompt (while doing a continuous ping in the background) once the command line declares that there's a "request time out", intermittent connection, etc. So that there wouldn't be a need to manually check the status of the connection.

Comment: what do you mean by ping data ? the output in console / the ICMP packet content ?

Comment: This kind of data that can be read in the command line: 
Reply from 63.24.3.105: bytes=32 time=761ms TTL=127

Comment: It's better for you to write a simple C# program ( or Java , programming language doesn't really matters ) to ping your target server non-stop & write results to log / database .

Comment: Okay. Thanks for confirming the possibility of retrieving the data from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this was asked 2 months ago, but it was never answered. Hopefully this will still be useful to someone. Granted, it's much easier to implement using a "real" programming language, but sometimes you need something that uses only built-in commands.

Configure as needed via environment variables (examples shown). To be polite, you probably want to use much longer timeouts if you don't own the server you're pinging.

```
    @echo off
    cls
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    REM Configuration:
    set SERVER=google.com
    set TIMEOUT_AFTER_PING_FAIL_SECONDS=5
    set TIMEOUT_AFTER_PING_SUCCEED_SECONDS=10
    set TIMEOUT_AFTER_LINK_DOWN_SECONDS=15
    set DECLARE_LINK_DOWN_FAILS=5

    set CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT=0
    :Start
    set PING_RESULT=Failure
    for /f "delims=" %%X in ('ping /n 1 %SERVER%') do (
       set TEMPVAR=%%X
       if "Reply from"=="!TEMPVAR:~0,10!" set PING_RESULT=Success
       )
    goto:!PING_RESULT!

    :Success
    echo Ping Succeeded
    set CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT=0
    call:Sleep %TIMEOUT_AFTER_PING_SUCCEED_SECONDS%
    goto:Start

    :Failure
    set /A CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT+=1
    echo Ping Failed !CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT! Time(s)
    if !CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT!==%DECLARE_LINK_DOWN_FAILS% (call:LinkDownHandler&goto:Start)
    call:Sleep %TIMEOUT_AFTER_PING_FAIL_SECONDS%
    goto:Start

    :Sleep
    REM See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317020/windows-batch-sleep
    setlocal
    set /A ITERATIONS=%1+1
    ping -n %ITERATIONS% 127.0.0.1 >nul
    goto:eof

    :LinkDownHandler
    echo Link is Down
    set CONSECUTIVE_FAIL_COUNT=0
    REM Add additional link-down handler actions here
    call:Sleep %TIMEOUT_AFTER_LINK_DOWN_SECONDS%
    goto:eof
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Although I have yet to dissect and understand your code, I would like to thank you for your effort. Btw, is this a script file?

Comment: This is a standard Windows batch file (tested and works under Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7). Copy it to a file with a .bat extension (ex. ServerCheck.bat), change the configuration variables as needed, then just type ServerCheck (you don't need to add ".bat").

Comment: Of course, you also need to add commands to do something useful when the state changes (a message sent to the console isn't very useful!).