# sleep function in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, wait, sleep

I am creating a batch file to run a program on my desktop `xyz.exe` for 4 hours, then close it for 1 hour and repeat the process. Here is my script.

```
:a
START C:\Users\Mukul\Desktop\xyz.exe
SLEEP 14400
taskkill /F /IM xyz.exe
SLEEP 3600
goto :a
```

According to [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php), the script should wait. It also says:

```
SLEEP 10
```

will delay execution of the next command by 10 seconds. so `SLEEP 14400` should delay the execution by 4 hours.

Current results:
Next command gets executed as soon as the first command completed.

Desired results:
Next command should wait for 4 hours before executing the last command.

Comment: You can also do this: `powershell sleep 14400`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows batch: sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317020/windows-batch-sleep)

Comment: for windows 10 pro as of sept 21 2020, sleep is not recognized but timeout is. the parameter of timeout is in seconds. e.g Timeout /t 10 
<BR>
For waiting indefinitely until a key press: timeout /t -1.

<br> for details see timeout /? in the command prompt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use bash's [`timeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/timeout) command.

For example:

```
@echo off
echo Hi
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
```

- `/t` is not mandatory
- 1 is the amount of second(s) to wait
- `/nobreak` ensures the user can't skip the wait
- `> nul` redirects output to nothing, so you don't see anything

Answer (score 5):

SLEEP command may not be supported by your Windows version. Try this:

```
:a
START C:\Users\Mukul\Desktop\xyz.exe
TIMEOUT 14400
taskkill /F /IM xyz.exe
TIMEOUT 3600
goto :a
```

Comment: since when it doesn't support ? i use windows 10.
thanks for answer

Comment: not sure when but probably since they start allowing windows key+sleep for "power and sleep setting" that can control time  before  windows goes to sleep

Answer (score 2):

First off: Bash and Batch are very different languages.
Now, the answer.
I prefer the `ping` command over the `sleep` command, for it's easy switching between seconds and milliseconds:

```
ping -n 11 127.0.0.1>nul
```

That command pauses for 10 seconds then resumes.
Or:

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10001 >nul
```

Which also pauses for 10 seconds, but in milliseconds.

Either can be adapted into:

```
:a
start C:\Users\Mukul\Desktop\xyz.exe
ping -n 14401 127.0.0.1>nul
taskkill /F /IM xyz.exe
ping -n 3601 127.0.0.1>nul
goto a
```

**DISCLAIMER**: I have **NOT** tried the final piece of code (because I don't have 4 extra hours to do something).

Comment: 1.1.1.1 will actually go somewhere >> https://1.1.1.1/ (https://1.0.0.1/)

Comment: No, no and no. Even if this is the Microsoft Windows world, and not everything there has sense even if it sometime works, this is still information technology and pinging someone to wait some seconds can't be the answer. Moreover, why pinging a private host (`1.1.1.1` is Cloudflare) and not localhost? Downvote.