# Scala blocking queue, making proper wait

Tags: multithreading, scala, queue, blockingqueue

I have to implement a blocking and synchronized queue in scala.

If I don't miss something, synchronizing is pretty simple, but for my queue to be blocking I could only think of that (which works) :

```
def pop() : T = {
    this.synchronized
    {
        _read()
        if(_out.isEmpty) throw new Empty()
        val ret = _out.head
        _out = _out.tail
        _length -= 1
        return ret
    }
}

def waitPop() : T =
{

    var ret : Option[T] = None

    // Possibly wait forever
    while(ret.isEmpty)
    {
        try { ret = Some(pop) }
        catch { case e : Empty => Thread.sleep(1000) }
    }

    ret.get
}
```

The problem here is `Thread.sleep`, it could compromise performance, couldn't it ?
Of course, putting a lower value would mean consuming more of the CPU.
Is there a way to wait properly ?

Thanks.

Comment: I took a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107593/what-are-trade-offs-for-busy-wait-vs-sleep
But, in my case, the scheduler doesn't know what I'm waiting does it ?

Comment: You want to use `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`.

Comment: Thanks, that IS what I was looking for (I had a hard time with all those futures and all).
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Voo, I got what I needed :

```
def waitPop() : T =
{
    this.synchronized
    {
        while(isEmpty) wait

        pop
    }
}
```

While in push, I added `notifyAll` (still in a `synchronized` block).
`notify` was also working, but with `notifyAll` the result appears less deterministic.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you may block in `push` because you limit the size of the stack, then yes you need `notifyAll`, otherwise `notify` should be a bit more efficient because otherwise you wake up all threads although only one could do work. `notfiy` doesn't give any fairness guarantees though so yes that may be useful in some situations.

Comment: I also added this, because I have to make something the less deterministic possible (doesn't matter why I guess), with `notify`, I got all my thread get an element from the queue in the very same order I started them.